# How can I test the output of ant command in a Shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, ant

I need to test if the output of "ant start" command is "Build success" or "Build Fail"

My code is:

```
# Start the App
sleep 20
ant -f start
if [ ! $? = 0 ] || [ "Here I have to test if ant start command output was Build Success or Build Failure" ] ; then
    echo "*** Failed to start" 
        Exit 2
fi
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am also testing [! $? = 0] OR that the output of ant start command was Build Fail.

Comment: I dont know how to test if the output of ant start command is build success or build fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
if ant -f start
then
    echo "*** Build started" 
else
    echo "*** Failed to start" 
    Exit 2
fi
```

OR else:

```
ant -f start
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "*** Build started" 
else
    echo "*** Failed to start" 
    Exit 2
fi
```

Comment: So if ant start command outputs: build failure, $? variable will never be 0..is that correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ant -f start
antRet=$?


if [ $antRet -ne 0 ];then
    echo "*** Failed" 
    exit 1;
else
     echo "*** Build started"    
    exit 0;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIX-compatible:

```
# Start the App
sleep 20
cmd_out=$(ant -f start)
if [ $? -ne 0 ] || echo "$cmd_out" | grep -q "Build Fail"; then
    echo "*** Failed to start" 
    exit 2
fi
```

If you are using `bash`, the output check is simpler:

```
sleep 20
cmd_out=$(ant -f start)
if [[ $? != 0 || $cmd_out = Build\ Fail ]]; then
    echo "*** Failed to start" 
    exit 2
fi
```